# How can I find the index of the maximum element with recursive functions?

Tags: python, recursion

For an assignment, I have to find the maximum element's index recursively. How can I do that?

I've tried the following function, but I keep getting wrong results:

```
def maxElement(A):
    if len(A)==1:
        return A[0]
    else:
        max=maxElement(A[1:])
        if A[0]>max:
            return A[0]
        else:          
            return max


A=[9, 16, 100, 36, 4, 25, 1, 81, 49, 9, 64]
print(maxElement(A))
```

I should get `2`, since it's the third element, but I keep getting `100`.

Comment: ı want to index of max in a list ı can find max value this list but ı cannot find the index can you help me please ?

Comment: Finds the index of the maximum number in a List.

Comment: please do not max funtion please algorithm answer

Comment: 100 is max value. that is why output will be 2

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711397

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Recursive function to find the largest number in the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711397/python-recursive-function-to-find-the-largest-number-in-the-list)

Comment: is it index or max ? ı want index of max

Comment: and ı have to do defain a function

Answer (score 1):

the simple way is with `max` and `index` as @Harwee show, but you can also do both with this recursive function

```
def find_max_pos(lista,pos=0,pos_item=None) -> "(index,item)":
    if not lista:
        return pos_item
    else:
        item  = lista[0]
        resto = lista[1:]
        if pos_item is None:
            return find_max_pos(resto,pos+1,(pos,item))
        prev = pos_item[1]
        if prev >= item:
            return find_max_pos(resto,pos+1,pos_item)
        else:
            return find_max_pos(resto,pos+1, (pos,item) )
```

with this you keep track of your current position with the `pos` argument and the max item and its position with the `pos_item`, the base case is the empty list in with case you return what you have and in each iteration you reduce the list, you can modify this so you don't keep copying the list over an over with additional arguments `max_pos` like this

```
def find_max_pos_v2(lista,pos=0,pos_item=None,max_pos=None) -> "(index,item)":
    if max_pos is None:
        max_pos = len(lista)
    if pos >= max_pos:
        return pos_item
    item  = lista[pos]
    if pos_item is None:
        return find_max_pos_v2(lista,pos+1,(pos,item),max_pos)
    prev = pos_item[1]
    if prev >= item:
        return find_max_pos_v2(lista,pos+1,pos_item,max_pos)
    else:
        return find_max_pos_v2(lista,pos+1,(pos,item),max_pos )
```

if you only want the position or the max element modify the use of `pos_item` accordingly.

Notice that I make all additional arguments default to some convenient value and handle then accordingly.

example

```
>>> A=[9, 16, 100, 36, 4, 25, 1, 81, 49, 9, 64]
>>> find_max_pos(A)
(2, 100)
>>> find_max_pos_v2(A)
(2, 100)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you meant 
something similar to this this will do the job

```
A=[9, 16, 100, 36, 4, 25, 1, 81, 49, 9, 64]
x  = max(A)
print A.index(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of the max element its index and the current index as you go, returning the index of the max element:

```
def max_ind(l, i, mx, mx_i):
    if not l:
        return mx_i
    if l[0] > mx:
        mx = l[0]
        mx_i = i
    i += 1
    return max_ind(l[1:], i, mx, mx_i)


l = [9, 16, 100, 36, 4, 25, 1, 81, 49, 9, 64]
print(max_ind(l, 0, l[0], 0))
2
```

If you want the element and the index:

```
def max_ind(l, i, mx, mx_i):
    if not l:
        return mx_i, mx
    if l[0] > mx:
        mx = l[0]
        mx_i = i
    i += 1
    return max_ind(l[1:], i, mx, mx_i)


l = [9, 16, 100, 36, 4, 25, 1, 81, 49, 9, 64]
print(max_ind(l, 0, l[0], 0))
(2, 100)
```

You can also do it without slicing:

```
def max_ind(l, mx, i, mx_i):
    if not l.__length_hint__():
        return mx_i
    e = next(l)
    if e > mx:
        mx = e
        mx_i = i
    i += 1
    return max_ind(l, mx, i, mx_i)


l = [9, 16, 100, 36, 4, 25, 1, 81, 49, 9, 64]
print(max_ind(iter(l), l[0], 0, 0))
```