# How to find the maximum value in a linked list recursively?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I need to find the maximum value in a linked list given the head of the list as a parameter recursively. I have no clue how to start the recursive part of the method. This is all I have so far.

```
int maxOfList(List M){  
    List max = M;
    if(M == null)
        return max;
    if(M.next > max){
        max = M.restOfTheInts;
        return maxOfList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does what you have so far work for a length 1 list?  If not, don't even try to consider the recursive case. (Hint: no it doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

In recursion, you often need an entry method and a worker method. The entry method is the special case that allows the worker method to work in all cases, and the worker does the recursion.

For example, your worker might be something like:

```
int maxOfList(int currentMax, List<int> listToCheck) {
  // Nothing to compare? currentMax is it!
  if (listToCheck == null || listToCheck.size() == 0) return currentMax;

  // Compare and return.
  List<int> restOfList = listToCheck.subList(1, listToCheck.size());
  return maxOfList(Math.max(currentMax, listToCheck.get(0)), restOfList);
}
```

And then to kick that off, you need your entry method:

```
int maxOfList(List<int> listToCheck) {
  return maxOfList(Integer.MIN_VALUE, listToCheck);
}
```

Comment: That's really only needed as an optimization, if it will be tail call optimized.  Without tail call optimization, no helper method is needed.

Comment: That's one reason.  Another reason is that the signature of a recursive method is almost always burdened with a parameter that is used only for recursion. In this case, `currentMax` is a parameter than the public API just doesn't need to know about.

Comment: My point is, you don't need the parameter at all, and thus don't need the helper.  The recursive call is just `return max(node.value, maxOfList(node.tail))`

Comment: Good point. I suppose I was being extra defensive about list being null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

So, for recursion to effectively work, you need to have the whole context visible inside the function.

```
int maxOfList(List m) {
     if(m.next == null)
          return m;
     int previousMax = maxOfList(m.next);
     if(m > previousMax)
          return m;
     else
          return previousMax;
}
```

Comment: You may need to provide an implementation of `List.next` to explain that fully.

Comment: Agreed Paul. My answer was simply an algorithmic solution. Implementation into the Java language, in my opinion, should be left for cee for him to understand recursion effectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxValue(List m){
   return maxValue(m, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}

int maxValue(List m, int num){
  if(m.next == null){
     if(m.data > num)
     return num = m.data;
  }
  return maxValue(m.next, num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward. In order to achieve a recursive solution, think about all these steps:

- **What's the recursive idea?** The maximum of a list `{L}` is the `max(Li, {L} - Li)`, where `Li` is the current element;
- **What's the stop condition?** We know that if a list is empty, the maximum could be something that any number will be greater, let's say `MIN_INT`;
- **Putting all together:** So, at the end we could say that a pseudo-code would look like this:

`int maxOfList(List M) {
    if(M == null)
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max = maxOfList(M.next);
    return M.value > max ? M.value : max;
}`

I am supposing that the linked list has its content in `value` and points to next element in `next` (tail pointing to `null`). If you find any further problems, take a look at this posts:

[Finding Max value in an array using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590242/finding-max-value-in-an-array-using-recursion)

[Python: Recursive function to find the largest number in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711397/python-recursive-function-to-find-the-largest-number-in-the-list)